# localStorage stores HTMLTextAreaElement instead of value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a page with 33 textareas, if the user fills any of them, I want to store them, but also leave empty spaces in the list/array of localStorage, meaning, if you use entry 0, and entry 33 only, 31 of them in the middle would be empty because their positions matter. I made some progress, and the best I got to was this script:

```
var cells = 33;

function savePlanner() {
    for (i = 0; i < cells; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem('planner', document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i]);
    }
}
```

The `savePlanner` function is called on the `onclick` of the button tag in the `HTML` file.

```
<div class="content-output"><textarea></textarea></div>
        <table class="u-full-width">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hour</th>
                <th>Activity</th>
                <th>Note</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea id="hour" class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea id="hour" class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea id="hour" class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="user-input"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
```

These `textarea` repeat themselves for 11 times, and since there are 3 columns of them, I have 33 entries.

But if I use `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i]`, what I get stored is `HTMLTextAreaElement`, and if I concatenate `value` to it, it doesn't store anything, even though some of my `textareas` are filled. What am I missing here?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('planner'` overwrites a single value every time ... so, you'll get ONE, the 33rd cell only. `localStorage.getItem('planner', i)` ... getItem doesn't take TWO arguments

Comment: try ... `localStorage.setItem('planner' + i` and `localStorage.getItem('planner' + i)`

Comment: Thanks, you are right about `getItem()`, it just takes one parameter, gonna check on it. But I get 33 entries for `setItem` without concatenating `value` to it, and all of them are `HTMLTextAreaElement`. Am I missing what you are saying here? If I do `localStorage.setItem('planner' + i)` won't I be missing the key entry that is required and thus throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you do `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')` on every loop? That's very inefficient, consider replacing the loop with `document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(...)`.

Comment: Because I'm not (yet) very proficient in Javascript. Gonna look into it. Thanks! Any idea on the actual question though? Why is it returning `HTMLTextAreaElement` instead of the values in the cells?

Comment: your code as is would not ... only if you don't use `.value` would it end up the way you say ... i.e. your code doesn't match your claimed result

Comment: At present your question is off–topic because you haven't put enough code in the question to show the issue. Reduce your code to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue (i.e. add some HTML, remove unnecessary code). `document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i].value` should "work".

Comment: `But I get 33 entries for setItem` no, you get the same value 33 times ... there is only ONE localStorage item called `planner` - you just display it 33 times!

Comment: Oh, I see. So I have to set a different `localStorage` for every entry? Not sure how I missed that in MDN's documentation, thanks!

Comment: Added some HTML to the question @RobG, hope that's enough, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localStorage.setItem('planner', document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i]);
```

Is sticking a HTMLTextAreaElement into storage and localStorge can only store string, the getString method on a HTMLTextAreaElement will return HTMLTextAreaElement.

You want

```
document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[i].value
```

which is the value of the text area, not the DOM element.